# Flex-flow: column wrap. How to set container's width equal to content?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a container and several inner divs.

```
.container {
 display: inline-flex;
 flex-flow: column wrap;
 max-height: 500px;
}
.element {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #000;
}
```

Now I have 3 flex columns.

What I expected:
Container's width becomes equal to the sum of columns' width (660px).

What I got:
Container's width becomes equal to the first column's width.

The pen:
http://codepen.io/korsun/pen/zGpQrZ

Why? When I change flex-direction to row and max-height to max-width everything goes just as expected. Is there a way to make my container's width equal to content width?

Comment: The problem is in how the browser handle the laying out of the element.
Maybe you can submit bug to browser developer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your "**.wrap**" container is set to "**inline-block**". You will want the container of "**.container**" to be set to "block" and then a defined with to contain the blocks overall.
2. Your "**.container**" is set to "**inline-flex**" which is then doing the same thing as ".wrap" when you add the inline element into the picture. Setting this back to "**flex**" should fix your problem.
3. Your elements inside the container should typically set to "**flex: [number]**" and a containing width. The current with of "200" is constraining and unfortunately unresponsive. Setting a max-width of 200 will both give it the width desired plus the responsive aspect which you can control with media queries.

http://codepen.io/mmcshinsky/pen/bd927e31d2df2f9180a5b7fcf1df2740/

```
.wrap {
  display: block;
  max-width: 660px;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  max-height: 500px;
}

.element {
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #000;
  flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work in Safari.. more here: https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs/issues/66

Comment: Does not work in IE 11. I suppose because you are doing with min-height on flexbox, this does not work there

Comment: You explicitly set max width to 660px but if there are 7 elements it won't work because the with must be more. I have the same problem and need dynamic solution

Comment: Thank you very much!!!